# Graph data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

Let's Say I have  `MyClass{ private LargeMatrix mtrx; hashCode(){...}}`

JGraphT (maybe all Graph data structures) seems to be using Hash table to map the vertices. So will that affect the speed when I'm using the MyClass instead of `String l1,l2,l3` ?

What are the pros and cons in that case ? Should I override hashcode(remove matrix hashcode ) ? Is there a graph that uses references instead of hashtable ?

so My code was:

```
package ann;

import org.jgrapht.DirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleDirectedGraph;

/**
 * @author marmoush
 * 
 */
public class Network
{
    DirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge>  diGraph;
    String l1="hello1";
    String l2="hello1";
    String l3="hello3";
    /**
     * 
     */
    public Network()
    {

        diGraph = new SimpleDirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
        diGraph.addVertex(l1);
        diGraph.addVertex(l2);
        diGraph.addVertex(l3);

        diGraph.addEdge(l1, l2);
        System.out.println(diGraph.containsEdge(l1,l2));
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: loops not allowed
    at org.jgrapht.graph.AbstractBaseGraph.addEdge(Unknown Source)
    at ann.Network.<init>(Network.java:28)
    at test.TestNetwork.main(TestNetwork.java:9)
```

Because (I think) `l1.hashCode()==l2.hashCode()`

**EDIT:**
Matrices might be zeros sometimes or ones, they change over time so I would try to come up with something that differentiate between those objects, and that seems to be stupid solution. Why can't the graph just select vertices by there position in a vector or something ?

Should I reinvent the wheel ? with a graph that uses Vectors instead of hashtables ? or there is a work around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a Vertex class and implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` appropriately. The speed impact is not that big, it can even be faster if the id of the vertex is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

well it does make sense, 
your objectl1 is the same as l2, even if it is stored in the memory at a different location, for the graph it is the same vertex.

is there a reason why you need to identical vertices in the graph? maybe there is a workaround

Comment: sometimes those matrices might be zeros, and they will change over time. so no way I would allow it to be selected through hashcode

Comment: l1 and l2 will never be stored in different locations in memory. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Java, so l1 and l2 are guaranteed to point to the *exact same* location in memory. It's a nice feature of the language, and it speeds up string processing a lot, but it will screw you up in situations like this.

That's why you're getting the loop exception. I suspect that you want an undirected graph structure here.

For a reference, see the Java Language Spec [section 3.10.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html):

> - Literal strings within the same class    (§8) in the same package (§7)
>     represent references to the same
>     String object (§4.3.1).
> - Literal    strings within different classes in    the same package
>     represent references    to the same
>     String object.
> - Literal    strings within different classes in    different packages
>     likewise represent    references to
>     the same String object.

Comment: just as clarification, l1 and l2 are guaranteed to point to the exact same location in memory because they're both initialized with String literals. If l2 where initialized like `String l2=new String("hello1")` then `l1==l2` will be false.

Comment: still the hashtable result is the same which throws an exception

Comment: My problem isn't with string, it's with HashTable being used as indexer, I want to use a List or a Vector

Comment: @Soronthar - Correct. Thank you for the clarification. I learned something new today.

Comment: @ismail marmoush - I'm not familiar with the JGraphT framework, so I can't really say whether or not using a List or Vector would even be possible, though it should work. A HashTable should hash the two identical strings to the same location, which a list will (probably) not do. Do *not* use the Vector class -- it synchronizes every method and will slow down your code unnecessarily. The Vector class is a legacy relic, and has been for more than a decade now.

Comment: @ismail marmoush - Additional thought: what constitutes node equality? If the node is evaluated on its content, then changing indexing structures won't help you. You have two identical nodes, therefore a digraph won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this kind of graph doesn't allow loops. You have to change the kind of graph to `AbstractBaseGraph` where you can set the variable `loopAllowed` to `true`, or you could try to change this variable in your `SimpleDirectedGraph`.

Problem: I wasn't able to change the variable in the `SimpleDirectedGraph`, but you can use other types of graphs that allow you do it.

I hope I could help you.